# Django 1.8: Is there a User-to-User messaging app that works both via the website and email?

Tags: django, email, django-messages

I'm looking for a way for users to message each other via the website, with their own inbox, sent, etc folders, and to receive and reply to these messages via email as well. The email addresses used for replying are generated by the app to hide user's real emails. The app sits in the middle of the two users via the site and via email.

Both `django-messages` and `django-postman` give very little information about what email-related features they have. Can either do this, or is there an alternative?

Thanks

Comment: I just wondered if you got anywhere with this.  I'm interested in exactly the same question and I'm looking for a solution

Comment: Didn't implement the feature, was for a side project and couldn't put the time in

Answer (score 0):

[django-messages](https://github.com/arneb/django-messages) includes pretty much all you asked for including inbox, outbox, trash and many more goodies

[django-postman](https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/overview) seems even better and is in active development

try out these packages they both include documentation.

Comment: But neither state in the docs that they perform this email-to-app-to-email feature, only that they notify the user via email

Comment: they are both open source and already have most of the functionality you need, you can probably try to extend them to support the features you need.